# Is a core data migration required when changing the Transformer for a Transformable attribute?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

After getting the error described at the link below, I have set the Transfomer to NSSecureUnarchiveFromData (it was nil before) for an entity's attribute.

[CoreData crash error Xcode 11 Beta, IOS 13 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144796/coredata-crash-error-xcode-11-beta-ios-13-beta)

I am using the transformable type to store an array.

Everything seems to work fine when I update my app, and data is preserved, however, I haven't had to perform any kind of migration. I just made the changes in the same xcdatamodel that I had before.

Why haven't I had to do a migration, or should I have done one and could problems be caused further down the line if I don't do one?

Comment: Did you manage to store any data for that attribute before you got the error, if no then I don't see why a migration would be needed.

Comment: Yes, as the app is already on the app store. I tested by downloading my app from the App Store, storing some stuff to Core Data, and then running my app from Xcode - the data was retained.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do migration. Here is some more information for this

[Core Data: Rename Attribute without having issues with users and their current data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391719/core-data-rename-attribute-without-having-issues-with-users-and-their-current-d/39401942)

Comment: Why is there a need to do a migration though? I have just changed the transformer type.